# BlackBerry - Avoiding Encryption

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

As part of the application, we are creating a file myApp.cfg in the "file:///store/home/user/" location  on the device. The encryption on the device is enabled. Due to this, the myApp.cfg is being renamed to myApp.cfg.rem and the application is not able to read the file anymore. Apart from the obivious answer of not enabling the encryption, is there any way to over come this issue. Is there any area/path on the device where the files are not encrypted? Note this question is for BlacBerry OS 7 and below.

Thanks
Krish

Answer (score 1):

The exact same question has been asked on the BB forums here:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-Avoiding-Encryption/td-p/2552487

Mark Sohm has answered as follows:

The basic answer is to use ExtendedFileConnection, which can read and write the .rem files.  Have a look at the JavaDocs and let us know if you get stuck.

JavaDocs: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/file/ExtendedFileConnection.html